# How do I mark an item as a duplicate in Amazon?

Tags: amazon

Amazon often has two items with vastly different prices. Is there anyway to mark the two items as a duplicate or to inform Amazon of this?

- [Heil Sound RS-1 12" Riser for PL-2T Overhead Broadcast Boom](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001RMJBFA)
- [Heil Sound RS-1 Riser with Surface Mount for PL2T Boom System](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001HBX2MO)

Lest another person answer claiming that one is Amazon and one isn't here is another dupe in the audio category,

- [Audio-Technica AT831B Lavalier Condenser Microphone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MNO59O)
- [Audio-Technica AT831b Lavalier Microphone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002RL8TS0)

Comment: Dupes are getting out of hand. The same LG Infinim Bluetooth headset is both [[1](http://www.amazon.com/LG-Electronics-INFINIM-Bluetooth-Headset/dp/B00NW2JBYO/)] and [[2](http://www.amazon.com/LG-Oracle-number-4538C-Infinim/dp/B00Q5D0LUU)], which is 20% more expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Even though back in 2013 [it wasn't possible to easily suggest merging products](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2451182), now it is:

Go to the [Contact us](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/hz/contact-us) page, select *Products and inventory* → *Product page issue*, then *Merge or split product page*:

[image: Merge ASINs]

After you've reported a duplicate, you can check on the progress at https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/case-dashboard/lobby.html

---

Alas, the merge isn't going to happen quickly if the products have different UPCs (which apparently sellers ensure is the case by buying different UPCs). Here is the reply I got after asking to merge three listings for the same LG Infinim Bluetooth headset:

> Greetings,
>
> Thank you for writing to Amazon.com. I understand that you want us to merge the ASINs B00NW2JBYO, B00Q5D0LUU, B00QQYZS0Q in our catalog. I will surely assist you in this regard.
>
> I have viewed your request and upon investigation I noticed that the UPC of the ASIN does not match as per our catalog records. Kindly note that in cases where the UPC does not match, we at seller support do not have the authority to process the request from our end.
>
> ```
> ================
> ASIN UPC
> ================
> B00NW2JBYO: 00874305006773   
> B00Q5D0LUU: 00849944010405
> B00QQYZS0Q: 00874305006933
> ```
>
> However, to make sure our catalog is error free and updated, I am proactively forwarding this issue to our catalog department internally, who have the authority to take decisions in this regard and in such cases. Kindly note that this is done through a systematic process that requires review and research of the duplicate items, which can take time to resolve. Once the duplicated items are confirmed, they will be merged into a single ASIN by the concerned team. I request your understanding and co-operation in this regard.
>
> I have to inform you that we would not be able to update you on the status of the request in this regard. However, as soon as the ASINs are merged, all the sellers will receive an email informing about the merge and the reason as to why it was merged.
>
> I sincerely apologize for any inconvenience caused. Kindly write back to us in case you need any further assistance in this regard and I will be glad to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Those two items are different. Amazon allows [other retailers to sell on their system](http://services.amazon.com/content/sell-on-amazon.htm/ref=footer_soa?ld=AZFSSOA). The second link you have is sold by Amazon. The first link is being sold by another vendor.

Because of this, Amazon may list the exact same item for sale at multiple different prices.

Comment: What? that's not true, [95% of Amazon items are sold by both Amazon and other retailers on the same page.](http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B000CZ0R42/ref=dp_olp_new_map?ie=UTF8&condition=new)

Comment: Yes, but retailers can also sell things directly through Amazon, as if Amazon were selling them. Look for the text "Ships from and sold by Music123." on your first link. That's not Amazon. The second link is.

Comment: That's only because they have different titles, thus the dupe. Retailers aren't supposed to list all of their items when there is already a product page -- they're supposed to compete and list as retailers for the product, like the link provided. What do you think if 1,000 users all wanted to sell the RS-1 I gave as an example? When you did a search for it, you'd see 1,000 thumbnails and 400 pages with different prices? No, they're supposed to show up like the SM58 that I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

You can suggest changes to a page description through the "update product info" link under "Product details" or in the feedback block at the bottom of the page.

Here is a link to the "update product info" for the first product you mentioned: "[Heil Sound RS-1 Riser with Surface Mount for PL2T Boom System](https://www.amazon.com/gp/gfix/makeCorrections.html?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B001HBX2MO&merchantID=A3ET1CHCB2RN4K&ref_=gfix-hmd-catalog&storeID=musical-instruments)"

It will not let you mark it as a duplicate though but it will let you suggest the same title for it.